# JSF WebContent rendering methods not working when entering subdirectory

Tags: java, html, jsf, rendering

I have a web App running in liberty that utilizes jsf, made in eclipse. I am attempting to place my rendered pages (.xhtml files) in  subdirectories in order to organize the URL paths.

Example: 
http://1sy:9011/Batch/main.xhtml (Not actual Links. Just an Example)

To look like this: http://1sy:9011/Batch/subdirectory/main.xhtml (Example: Not a link)

where subdirectory is a folder within the webcontent directory. The problem with this is that if I use a bean method to call the page in the sub-directory, any method within that page that calls a page outside of this sub-directory will no longer worked when an input within a form is activated on that page within the sub-directory. How can I render pages outside of the sub-directory once I have called a page within it? I will place sample code with an explanation below.

```
public String viewGroups(){ 

return "subdirectory/viewgroups";
}
```

This method will render the .xhtml viewgroups, which is in the subdirectory(folder) "subdirectory" within the webcontent folder, but if I press a button on view groups that calls the following method:

```
public String editSelectedGroup(){
return "editgroup";
}
```

editgroup.xhtml will not be called. editgroup.xhtml is in the root of the webcontent directory, back outside of the subdirectory.

Comment: I could issue the method ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContectPath() + "/editgroup.xhtml");

Comment: I believe this would redirect me outside of the sub-directory, but I would have to perform that redirect for all methods that call pages that are not in a subdirectory. I am certain that there is another way.

Comment: Pages unreachable...!!! And Please post images inline instead of links to active applications

Comment: After the page, viewgroups.xhtml is called. All of the other pages, which are in the root of webcontent, are now unreachable.

Comment: If I place any action in the method that is called on the page, such as a database call, or even just a system out, that action will take place, but the page will not be rendered when the " return 'xxxx' " is reached. The sys log shows no errors.